# C# String Function to get Characters inside two symbols

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a string that looks like this:

```
My name is **name**, and I am **0** years old.
```

And I need to extract the character/s inside the 2 asterisks `**GETTHISVALUE**`
and save it to a `List<string>`. What is the best way to do it? I prefer a built in c# function or LINQ. The output of the above example must be:

```
string[0] = "name"
string[1] = "0"
```

EDIT: I would like to mention that the values inside the **, can only be
letters and numbers and no white spaces either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Regex.

```
var reg = new Regex(@"\*\*([a-z0-9]+)\*\*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
var matches = reg.Matches(input);

var l = new List<string>();
foreach (Match m in matches)
    l.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: Your solution produces only **1** output: `"name"`

Comment: Note that your solution only matches lowercase letters _(and letters only)_. You should either do `[A-Za-z]` or specify the `IgnoreCase` option.

Comment: What about this pattern? `\*\*(.*?)\*\*`. Produces the wanted 2 outputs.

Comment: Yes, but as the op did not specify what can be part of the matches, I just added the simplest case, ie solving the original request. If there should be additional characters matched, the op can add the respective character classes or regex options

Comment: @khlr this would also produce only one output, because this would match from the first `**` before name to the last `**` after 0

Comment: No, it produces two.

Comment: Well in his question he has clearly written that he wants to match `**0**` too. Anyway, it's better to cover it all. :)

Comment: @khlr please see my edit, i don't understand regex wildcards please update answer to fit on my string criteria

Comment: @super-user : Please note that this does not include UPPERCASE letters. For that you should change the middle part to: `[A-Za-z0-9]+`.

Comment: Added the according option for IgnoreCase which then also captures UPPERCASE letters

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `Regex`:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(<input string here>, @"(?<=\*\*)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?=\*\*)");

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i ++)
{
    if (i != 0 && i % 2 != 0) continue; //Only match uneven indexes.
    myList.Add(matches[i].Value);
}
```

**Pattern explanation:**

```
(?<=\*\*)[^\*](?=\*\*)

(?<=\*\*)      The match must be preceded by two asterisks.
[A-Za-z0-9]+   Match any combination of letters or numbers (case insensitive).
(?=\*\*)       The match must be followed by two asterisks.
```

Comment: Your solution produces the following **3** outputs: `"name"`, `", and I am "` and `"0"`

Comment: @khlr : You're right... I'll look into it. Though wouldn't both the answers?

Comment: @khlr : This is only a temporary solution until I've found a Regex one, but I made the loop skip every other match.

Comment: @VisualVincent thank you for your input, I tested this and also works but the first answer also works exactly how I need it to. +1

Comment: @super-user : Choose the one you like :). I updated the code with a little fix, by the way. -- P.S: A tip for the future is that you don't need to say `@VisualVincent` if you are commenting on my answer/my question. The author will always be notified. :)

Comment: @super-user : Apart from derpirscher's answer not matching uppercase letters (easy fix) his is better as it doesn't match the same asterisks again. Mine does this, which is why I had to add the strange `if()`-statement inside the loop. :)

Comment: I see. Thanks for the extra info. Really helped.